# How to get the Uri from MediaStore via file path?

Tags: android

In my program, I want to save a selected ringtone by it's file path, and then set it as the current ringtone later.

I have got the ringtone uri from RingtonePreference, and get the file path of it from MediaStore database.

e.g.

```
Uri - content://media/internal/audio/media/29
Path - /system/media/audio/notifications/Ascend.mp3
```

Now, how to I get the ringtone Uri from the file path i saved ?

Since the ringtone already exist in MediaStore, I tried the following functions, but it's not working.

```
uriRingtone = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(szRingtonePath);
```

The Uri is not the same as the one I got from RingtonePreference.

```
uriRingtone - content://media/internal/audio/media
```

How do I query the MediaStore to get the Uri I need?

p.s. the reason that I don't store the ringtone Uri directly is that I found the Uri for the same ringtone might change sometimes in some device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you can recover the ringtone URI stored in the RingtonePreference is (as far as I know) by knowing the title of the song. Then you can query it by using a cursor to obtain the ringtone _id stored and with it you can build an URI:

```
String ringtoneTitle = "<The desired ringtone title>";
Uri parcialUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media"); // also can be "content://media/internal/audio/media", depends on your needs
Uri finalSuccessfulUri;

RingtoneManager rm = new RingtoneManager(getApplicationContext()); 
Cursor cursor = rm.getCursor();
cursor.moveToFirst();

while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    if(ringtoneTitle.compareToIgnoreCase(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE))) == 0) {
    int ringtoneID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        finalSuccessfulUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(parcialUri, "" + ringtoneID );
        break;
    }
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

where finalSuccessful uri is the uri pointing to the ringtone in the RingtonePreference.

Comment: It's actually probably better to use `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` or `MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to access the root URI.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this in a more generic manner for any content in the MediaStore.  I have to get the path from URIs and get the URI from paths.  The former:

```
/**
 * Gets the corresponding path to a file from the given content:// URI
 * @param selectedVideoUri The content:// URI to find the file path from
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the file path as a string
 */
private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedVideoUri,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    String filePath;
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaColumns.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(selectedVideoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

The latter (which I do for videos, but can also be used for Audio or Files or other types of stored content by substituting MediaStore.Audio (etc) for MediaStore.Video:

```
/**
 * Gets the MediaStore video ID of a given file on external storage
 * @param filePath The path (on external storage) of the file to resolve the ID of
 * @param contentResolver The content resolver to use to perform the query.
 * @return the video ID as a long
 */
private long getVideoIdFromFilePath(String filePath,
        ContentResolver contentResolver) {


    long videoId;
    Log.d(TAG,"Loading file " + filePath);

            // This returns us content://media/external/videos/media (or something like that)
            // I pass in "external" because that's the MediaStore's name for the external
            // storage on my device (the other possibility is "internal")
    Uri videosUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external");

    Log.d(TAG,"videosUri = " + videosUri.toString());

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns._ID};

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(videosUri, projection, MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
    videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

    Log.d(TAG,"Video ID is " + videoId);
    cursor.close();
    return videoId;
}
```

Basically, the `DATA` column of `MediaStore` (or whichever sub-section of it you're querying) stores the file path, so you use that info to look it up.

Comment: `DATA` column is depreacted

Answer (score 4):

Following code will return absolute path for content Uri of audio, video and image.

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);

        int idx;
        if(contentUri.getPath().startsWith("/external/image") || contentUri.getPath().startsWith("/internal/image")) {
            idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        }
        else if(contentUri.getPath().startsWith("/external/video") || contentUri.getPath().startsWith("/internal/video")) {
            idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
        }
        else if(contentUri.getPath().startsWith("/external/audio") || contentUri.getPath().startsWith("/internal/audio")) {
            idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA);
        }
        else{
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a try-finally and calling the cursor's close() method in the finally block.  Also the cursor.getColumnIndex() calls could throw NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

@dong221: Use Internal URI as a MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.