# Get Android song information from MediaStore with known Uri?

Tags: android, file, path, cursor, uri

I am querying for Android song data. I have this code

```
            System.out.println("URI COL: " + musicCursor.getString(uriColumn));
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(musicCursor.getString(uriColumn)));
            System.out.println("URI IS: " + uri.toString());
```

But the output is not right.

URI COL:
/storage/emulated/0/amazonmp3/Red Hot Chili Peppers/Stadium Arcadium/01 Dani California.wma

URI IS: file:///storage/emulated/0/amazonmp3/Red%20Hot%20Chili%20Peppers/Stadium%20Arcadium/01%20Dani%20California.wma

I tried to parse the Uri column and tried the fromFile method but neither option is giving me the format I need.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913427/how-to-get-the-uri-from-mediastore-via-file-path) shows an example of my problem, but no solution.

**Uri - content://media/internal/audio/media/29** :: is the format I need.
Path - /system/media/audio/notifications/Ascend.mp3 :: is the format I'm getting.

I only need that format because it appears Android Cursors only work in that format, which is completely illogical, especially when the DATA column only appears to give you the file path.

Comment: tried to get _id column?

Comment: @pskink Yeah I have the id. I'm not sure what you want me to do with it however.

Comment: what is the value of id?

Comment: it varies. I end up querying dynamically for each song. The first one is 356, or something like that.

Comment: so your `Uri` is **content://media/internal/audio/media/356** or something like that

Comment: Oh my god that make so much sense now! Thank you!